# Can't create two int in for statement

Tags: java, for-loop, int

Can you please help me make the following code work?

```
for(int a=0, b=0; a<101; b<102; a++; b++;) {
    stuff
}
```

Comment: Hint: exactly two semicolons are required.

Comment: SO is NOT a code writing service. Google "java for loop syntax" and try to figure it out - come back if you have trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got the initialization (first) part of the loop right.

The termination or condition (second) part of the loop should be evaluated to a boolean, so assuming you require an AND relation between the conditions on a and b, it becomes `a<101 && b<102`. You might want `||` (OR) instead, depending on your logic.

The increment (third) part of the loop should contain comma separated expressions (same as the initialization part which you already got right).

I also removed an extra ';' from the end.

```
for(int a=0, b=0; a<101 && b<102; a++, b++) { stuff }
```